# Can't use 'bin/magento' commands after running 'composer update --ignore-platform-reqs'

Tags: docker, bin-magento, composer-update

I have magento running from https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento , everything is working fine, but when i run `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs` then all `bin/magento` commands stop working.

[image]

Any ideas on what could be happening? and what would be the best solution? Deleting the vendor folder from the container and running `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs` ?

Thanks!